# Howto check if exists value in multidimensional dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, lambda

Have a multidimensional dictionary with host and ip address associated, by example:

```
items = {
    '10.0.0.1': [
        { 'host': 'abc.com', 'record_type': 'a', ... },
        { 'host': 'www.abc.com', 'record_type': 'cname', ... }
    ]
}
```

I have a new host and ip address to add to array, but, howto check if exists to prevent duplication?, example: need insert `www.abc.com` to `10.0.0.1` but without `cname`, canot make a clone of object to use `in` in a `if` conditional without record_type `cname`.

Using lambda? but howto try get object using lambda if have the host and ip address?

Comment: Are you trying to add more hosts to the same ip and trying to avoid duplicate hosts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

From your comment below, it looks like you're trying to store a set of `host` records, keyed uniquely on `ip` and `hostname`.

You should consider storing these in a 2-layer dictionary, like this:

```
items = {
    '10.0.0.1': {
        'abc.com': {'record_type': 'a', ... },
        'www.abc.com': {'record_type': 'cname', ... }
    },
    '10.0.0.2': {
        'xyz.com': {'record_type': 'a', ... },
        'www.xyz.com': {'record_type': 'cname', ... }
    }
}
```

Then you can easily access any item using the two key values:

```
def item_exists(ip, hostname):
    return ip in items.keys() and hostname in items[ip].keys()

def get_item(ip, hostname):
    return items[ip][hostname] if item_exists(ip, hostname) else None

def add_or_replace_item(ip, hostname, item):
    if ip not in items.keys():
        items[ip] = {}
    items[ip][hostname] = item

def add_item_if_not_exists(ip, hostname, item):
    if not item_exists(ip, hostname):
        add_or_replace_item(ip, hostname, item)
```

Comment: finnaly process each item in dictionary, if the dictionary is very heavy have a performance problem. It is posible with lambda?. The duplicated value to detect is only the host and ip address.

Comment: `lambda` is just a language construct: it won't improve performance.